# Make a custom theme translate-ready

Tags: theme-development, translation, multi-language

I created a my own theme, now I wish to make it translatable.

I made two files:

**theme.pot**

```
msgid "know_more"
msgstr "Vuoi saperne di più?"
```

**it_IT.po**

```
msgid "know_more"
msgstr "Vuoi saperne di più?"
```

Then in the index theme file i wrote:

```
<h2><?php _e('know_more',''); ?></h2>
```

But when I run the site appears just: *know_more*

Comment: You need complied MO files!

Comment: With the same format of PO file?

Comment: Have you read the handbook? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it properly, you need to generate a valid .mo file and load the text domain in your theme functions.php:

```
function wpse222346_localize_theme() {

    load_theme_textdomain( 'your_theme_domain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse222346_localize_theme' );
```

You can check the WordPress Codex for more info on the load_theme_textdomain function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain

Then you would call the translatable strings using your theme's text domain:

```
<h2><?php _e( 'know_more', 'your_theme_domain' ); ?></h2>
```

Also, it's strongly advised to use a tool for automating the creation of the POT files. It makes maintainability much easier. There are many options, such as [Poedit](https://poedit.net/), several online generators, [makepot.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Using_the_i18n_tools) and even a very nice plugin to do it from the WordPress Dashboard called [LocoTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/). Most of them will also help you creating the .PO and .MO files.